# Комментирование в VS2010

Tags: visual-studio

Надоело комментировать нужные участки кода с помощь/**/, вызывает неудобство особенно когда нужно комментировать участки кода в разных функциях. Как это можно сделать в VS2010 с помощью ее средств и какие горячие клавиши используются для комментирования.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, просто закомментировать ряд строчек: выделить их и последовательно нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Для раскомментирования то же, но вместо C надо жать U.

Другим, в общем-то, не пользуюсь .з.

Answer (score 0):

[Здесь](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=92CED922-D505-457A-8C9C-84036160639F&displaylang=en) плокаты по горячим кнопкам в VS 2010
А в самой студии тоже есть где посмотреть это дело: Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard
в правой панели можно написать кусок команды и сработает фильтр.